# Show gallery always after content

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, images, filters, gallery

I want to make gallery always displayed after post, regardless of where the shortcode was inserted.

If I write:

```
<section class="post-content clearfix">
<?php the_content( "Next..." ); ?>

<?php
// Retrieve all galleries of this post
$galleries = get_post_galleries_images( $post );

// Loop through all galleries found
foreach ( $galleries as $gallery ) {
    // Loop through each image in each gallery
    foreach ( $gallery as $image ) {
        echo '<img src="' . $image . '">';
    }
}
?>
```

The gallery will still be posted in the message and, as result, will be duplicated twice.

The possible solution is that I see - before the post is processed, find the shortcode in the text, remove it from there and add it to the end of the text.

Tell me please how to implement this method, or at least tell me what filter I should use to change the content before the shortcodes in it will be processed.

Comment: This question is almost 5 years old, is not it added any new features from that time to split the gallery from the post?

Comment: More like 4 years, but I think these answers still holds.

Comment: If the answer doesn't hold up, leave a comment and I'll update it. So far I've gotten no complaints or issues with the websites I run this code on.